# dplyr stack duplicated columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have received a data set much larger than, but similar to :

```
cost <- data.frame(Date=rep('1970-01-01', 3), Atr=runif(3),Atrb=runif(3),a=runif(3), b=runif(3), a=runif(3), b=runif(3),a=runif(3), b=runif(3))
names(cost) <- c('Date', 'Atr','Atrb','a','b','a','b','a','b')
```

There are many more columns than a and b that have duplicated names.
There are many more attribute columns than here.

Ideally I'd like to be able to use the `-c(Date:Atrb)` style to do any inclusion of exclusion.

I'd like to be able to create 2 types of tall data :

```
    Date         Atr     Atrb   Group    a         b     
1 1970-01-01 0.988181929 0.123  A        0.3836335 0.7793414
... 
1 1970-01-01 0.988181929 0.456  B        0.6464    0.98687
...
1 1970-01-01 0.988181929 0.789  C        0.123     0.3456
```

The other is:

```
    Date         Atr     Atrb   Group    Metric         Value     
1 1970-01-01 0.988181929 0.123    A        a              0.3836335 
1 1970-01-01 0.988181929 0.456    A        b              0.7793414
... 
1 1970-01-01 0.988181929 0.678    B        a              0.6464    
1 1970-01-01 0.988181929 0.345    B        b              0.98687
...
1 1970-01-01 0.988181929 0.789    C        a              0.123     
1 1970-01-01 0.988181929 0.456    C        b              0.3456
```

Appreciate any hints or tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution, but it requires first deduplicating the duplicated column names. There's probably a way to do that in a `dplyr` pipe using `rename_at` or something like that, but nothing's coming to me at the moment:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Deduplicate column names
idx = grep("^[ab]$", names(cost))
names(cost)[idx] = paste0(names(cost)[idx],".", rep(LETTERS[1:(length(idx)/2)], length(unique(names(cost)[idx]))))

cost.long = cost %>%
  gather(key, value, -Date, -Atr) %>%
  separate(key, into=c("Metric", "Group"))

cost.long
```

> ```
>          Date       Atr Metric Group      value
> 1  1970-01-01 0.5567203      a     A 0.43008996
> 2  1970-01-01 0.9421835      a     A 0.94488436
> 3  1970-01-01 0.4672264      a     A 0.70847981
> ...
> 16 1970-01-01 0.5567203      b     C 0.53797611
> 17 1970-01-01 0.9421835      b     C 0.02623668
> 18 1970-01-01 0.4672264      b     C 0.72440841
> ```

```
cost.long %>% spread(Metric, value)
```

> ```
>         Date       Atr Group         a          b
> 1 1970-01-01 0.4672264     A 0.7084798 0.34580760
> 2 1970-01-01 0.4672264     B 0.6537164 0.69052451
> 3 1970-01-01 0.4672264     C 0.6811653 0.72440841
> 4 1970-01-01 0.5567203     A 0.4300900 0.35140699
> 5 1970-01-01 0.5567203     B 0.7600863 0.76989417
> 6 1970-01-01 0.5567203     C 0.7536469 0.53797611
> 7 1970-01-01 0.9421835     A 0.9448844 0.61829407
> 8 1970-01-01 0.9421835     B 0.8929478 0.95985575
> 9 1970-01-01 0.9421835     C 0.9765727 0.02623668
> ```

**UPDATE:** To address your comment and updated example data: If `grep` is not an option, there are other approaches. For example:

```
idx = which(names(cost) %in% c("a","b"))

names(cost)[idx] = paste0(names(cost)[idx],".", rep(LETTERS[1:(length(idx)/2)], length(unique(names(cost)[idx]))))

head(cost)
```

> ```
>         Date       Atr      Atrb       a.A       b.B       a.C       b.A       a.B       b.C
> 1 1970-01-01 0.9437837 0.6600156 0.6084679 0.7855074 0.5800305 0.5174202 0.8040882 0.5707653
> 2 1970-01-01 0.7802974 0.5401236 0.4929647 0.5453363 0.5287559 0.3684388 0.5405421 0.2421765
> 3 1970-01-01 0.5336272 0.9807934 0.4530894 0.6434532 0.8517817 0.1269552 0.6914684 0.3035965
> ```

I don't get a warning with the following code:

```
cost %>%
  gather(key, value, -c(Date:Atrb)) %>%
  separate(key, into=c("Metric", "Group"))
```

> ```
>          Date       Atr      Atrb Metric Group     value
> 1  1970-01-01 0.9437837 0.6600156      a     A 0.6084679
> 2  1970-01-01 0.7802974 0.5401236      a     A 0.4929647
> 3  1970-01-01 0.5336272 0.9807934      a     A 0.4530894
> 4  1970-01-01 0.9437837 0.6600156      b     B 0.7855074
> 5  1970-01-01 0.7802974 0.5401236      b     B 0.5453363
> 6  1970-01-01 0.5336272 0.9807934      b     B 0.6434532
> 7  1970-01-01 0.9437837 0.6600156      a     C 0.5800305
> 8  1970-01-01 0.7802974 0.5401236      a     C 0.5287559
> 9  1970-01-01 0.5336272 0.9807934      a     C 0.8517817
> 10 1970-01-01 0.9437837 0.6600156      b     A 0.5174202
> 11 1970-01-01 0.7802974 0.5401236      b     A 0.3684388
> 12 1970-01-01 0.5336272 0.9807934      b     A 0.1269552
> 13 1970-01-01 0.9437837 0.6600156      a     B 0.8040882
> 14 1970-01-01 0.7802974 0.5401236      a     B 0.5405421
> 15 1970-01-01 0.5336272 0.9807934      a     B 0.6914684
> 16 1970-01-01 0.9437837 0.6600156      b     C 0.5707653
> 17 1970-01-01 0.7802974 0.5401236      b     C 0.2421765
> 18 1970-01-01 0.5336272 0.9807934      b     C 0.3035965
> ```

Comment: Hmm, your right the tricky part is the duplicated names... `grep` is not an option.  Can you alter it to this and then I think this is complete and can be accepted.  `idx = 3:8
names(cost)[idx] = paste0(names(cost)[idx],".", c(sapply(LETTERS[1:3],rep,times=2)) )`

Comment: Actually there is a problem with this approach as soon as you try to use `-c(Date:Atr)` syntax to exclude columns instead of the `-Date -Atr` syntax proposed here.  I have updated the question to be a minimal example that exposes this issue. the error seen is `Warning message:
Too many values at 12 locations: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18`

Comment: I'm not getting that warning. I've updated my answer to include your new example data.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table`'s extension of melt works great for this because you can melt multiple repeated columns at once:

```
require(data.table)

setDT(cost)
melt(cost, id=c("Date","Atr"), meas = patterns("^a$","^b$"), value.name=c("a","b"))

         Date        Atr variable          a          b
1: 1970-01-01 0.09643571        1 0.38316876 0.69935636
2: 1970-01-01 0.10714089        1 0.12154920 0.42598159
3: 1970-01-01 0.91581813        1 0.03301164 0.21327371
4: 1970-01-01 0.09643571        2 0.06866915 0.05604199
5: 1970-01-01 0.10714089        2 0.74418388 0.17013278
6: 1970-01-01 0.91581813        2 0.33784588 0.33794886
7: 1970-01-01 0.09643571        3 0.19680638 0.51427164
8: 1970-01-01 0.10714089        3 0.71372700 0.71134925
9: 1970-01-01 0.91581813        3 0.34700614 0.84975838
```

To get to your second form, you can simply use the standard implementation of `melt` more like `melt(cost2, id.vars=c("Date","Atr", "variable"))`

Comment: I'd prefer to use dplyr, but data.table will be used if there is no intuitive dplyr solution.... it looks like dplyr allows this to be done without too much pain.